# цикл foreach обрабатывает с повторами

Tags: php, foreach

Здравствуйте помогите разобраться с foreach смысл такой я хочу что бы при клике картинка увеличивалась, то есть показывала путь к оригинальному файлу,

```html
foreach  ($file_small as $val_small) {
          
                     foreach  ($file as $val) {
```

и на всякий случай весь код

```html
do {
    $file_small = explode(',', $myrow['filename_small']);

    $file = explode(',', $myrow['filename']);
  
               foreach  ($file_small as $val_small) {
          
                     foreach  ($file as $val) {
                  
                   
          
  
         print_r ("
  
                         
                           <div class='col-md-3'>

                              <caption>  

                                 

                                 <a href='../".$myrow['catalog'].$val."' class='fresco'> <img src='../".$myrow['catalog_small'].$val_small."' class='img-responsive' title='8 $Name' alt='8 $Name' /></a>
                                  <p>$Name <b>Ваш ид $id</b></p> 

                                  

                              </caption>
                              </div>
                           

                    ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($file_small as $key => $val_small) { 
  $val = $file[$key];
```